# How to create pre-signed URL in Objective C for S3 without SDK?

Tags: objective-c, macos, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, http-headers

I'm building a mac application and **not** using the AWS iOS SDK. The GET request I'm trying to build should follow this general format:

`"Authorization: AWS " + AWSAccessKeyId + ":"  + base64(hmac-sha1(VERB + "\n" 
                                 + CONTENT-MD5 + "\n" 
                                 + CONTENT-TYPE + "\n" 
                                 + DATE + "\n" 
                                 + CanonicalizedAmzHeaders + "\n" 
                                 + CanonicalizedResource))`

As provided as "pseudo syntax" in the [Amazon docs](http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTCanonicalization). I've been searching all over for clarification and it seems that according to a lot of people, many of the fields in the base64 hash are optional.

Below is what I came up with so far. But the response I get is an error from AWS saying "Unsupported Authorization Type" making reference to the 'Authorization' field in the header. I'm getting really stumped here. Any insight into how to debug or fix this?

Is there any other way to go about generating pre-signed urls in Obj C for S3?

```
-(NSURLRequest*) requestWithURL: (NSString*) reqURL
```

{

```
NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:reqURL]];
NSString* headerField = @"Authorization: ";
NSString* stringToSign = @"GET\n\n\n\n\n";

NSString* hash = [self hmacsha1:stringToSign key:SECRET_KEY];
NSString *authHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"AWS%@:%@", ACCESS_KEY_ID, hash];
NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
NSError *error = nil;


[mutableRequest addValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:headerField];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: mutableRequest returningResponse: &resp error: &error];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


return (NSURLRequest*) mutableRequest;
```

}

```
- (NSString *)hmacsha1:(NSString *)text key:(NSString *)secret {
    NSData *secretData = [secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *clearTextData = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    unsigned char result[20];
    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, [secretData bytes], [secretData length], [clearTextData bytes], [clearTextData length], result);

    char base64Result[32];
    size_t theResultLength = 32;
    NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithBytes:base64Result length:theResultLength];
    NSString* encodedData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[theData base64Encoding]];

    return encodedData;
}
```

The base64 encoding is done via an NSData addon from [this post](http://cybersam.com/ios-dev/http-basic-access-authentication-with-objective-c-and-ios)

Comment: You need to sync the 2 phases of **creating the URL** and **using it**. For example, if in the usage phase you are sending CONTENT-TYPE value, you must use it in the signing phase, and if you are not sending it, you shouldn't use it in the signing phase.

Comment: @Guy any chance you could be a little more specific, maybe use pseudo code to explain what would need to change? Do you mean I should only encode the parts of the string that are used and then append the newlines and not encode the whole string? Sorry it just seems a bit vague and abstract.

Comment: see below answer for more details

Answer (score 1):

To authenticate the query string you need to encode the stringToSign:

```
Signature = URL-Encode( Base64( HMAC-SHA1( YourSecretAccessKeyID, UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign ) ) ) );

StringToSign = HTTP-VERB + "\n" +
        Content-MD5 + "\n" +
        Content-Type + "\n" +
        Expires + "\n" +
        CanonicalizedAmzHeaders +
        CanonicalizedResource;
```

When a browser makes the GET request, it won't provide a Content-MD5 or a Content-Type header, nor will it set any x-amz- headers, so those parts of the StringToSign are left blank.

You will need to sign the following

```
GET\n
\n
\n
1175139620\n

/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg
```

And the request that the browser will send is:

```
GET /photos/puppy.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&
    Signature=NpgCjnDzrM%2BWFzoENXmpNDUsSn8%3D&
    Expires=1175139620 HTTP/1.1

Host: johnsmith.s3.amazonaws.com
```

Note that the Content-Type is omitted from both the request and the stringToSign, but `\n` remains in the stringToSign for it. The same of the rest of the *optional* parts.

See more examples in [Authentication Examples](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationExamples)

Check for more details in [AWS Documentations](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth)

Comment: I've been wading through AWS docs all week, thanks! Hm, so I came up with this, based on your description:
`  
    NSString* stringToSign = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GET\n\n\n%f\n%@", timestamp, resource_path];

    NSString* hash = [self hmacsha1:stringToSign key:SECRET_KEY];
    NSString *authHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"AWS%@:%@", ACCESS_KEY_ID, hash];`

Still getting "Unsupported Authorization Type" error back

Comment: What about your request code? Does it have the Content-Type value? It shouldn't. The same for the other *optional* fields.

Comment: Hm what I just wrote out was the entire signature value for the "Authentication:" header field; those newlines are in place of the optional fields. Other than that, no information is added to the NSURLRequest but the url, as you can sort of see in the orig. question.