# iOS: Create pre-signed URL using Sigv4 in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, pre-signed-url

I would like to create a **pre-signed URL** using **Sigv4** in Swift 3.0 and iOS 10.

Any suggestion on how to get started? I found this Amazon [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) but I am unable to find a way to do the signing process in iOS. The AWS classes that do this seem to be internal only (e.g. AWSIoTMQTTClient.h).

I found some Objective-c code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783749/how-to-create-pre-signed-url-in-objective-c-for-s3-without-sdk) but when I try to import it in my project some of the constructs are not recognised.

Hence I thought I ask here to see if anyone did this directly using Swift.

The URL format that I'd like is:

> https://blabla/blabla?blabla-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20170615T081418Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=3599&X-Amz-Credential=blabla%blabla%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=blabla

Comment: This could help https://medium.com/@lewisjkl/signing-aws4-31dcff1bf1f0

Comment: For future readers, this is doable using the SDK (now?) & I've answered the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77282078/4800344. I'm not sure if it's doable with Swift 3 and iOS 10 so I didn't answer this specific question, but certainly doable now.